# tail: Reading an entire file, and then following

Tags: tail

I would like a `tail -f` type of behavior that reads the entire file and then continues to follow it as it's written to.

---

**SOLUTION**

Based on the answer I accepted, this works: `tail -f -n +1 {filename}`

*Why it works:* The `-f` option continues to "follow" the file and output new lines as they are written to the file. The `-n +1` instructs `tail` to start reading the file from the first line. Using `-n -10` would start with the last ten lines of the file.

Comment: This is a comment not a question. And does tail not already do that: `tail -f -n 10000000000000000000` probably will show all the lines would it not? (maybe the 10000000000000000000 is a bit much :=) )

Comment: I believe `more fileName` would do just that

Comment: no..more will not add extra lines added to the file after more was started.

Comment: Presumably `tail -f -n 100...` will involve pre-reading the file to determine the number of lines, unless it's smart enough to work out an upper bound for the line count based on the file size.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291465/bash-alternative-to-cat-in-reading-writing-to-named-pipe

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use

```
tail -f -n +1
```

Using `man tail` will give you more details, the relevant excerpt follows.

```
<snip>Numbers having a leading plus (`+') sign are relative to the
beginning of the input, for example, ``-n +2'' starts the display at the
second line of the input.</snip>

-f      The -f option causes tail to not stop when end of file is
        reached, but rather to wait for additional data to be appended to
        the input.  The -f option is ignored if the standard input is a
        pipe, but not if it is a FIFO.

-n number
        The location is number lines.
```

Comment: Could you please add those "more details" to your answer? Please explain *why* and *how* your solution works. (Found your answer in the low quality posts queue.)

Comment: @kraxor You can find the "more details" by executing `man tail` (and reading it) like the answer says, or do an online search for "tail manpage" and read one of them. `tail` works by starting at a position in a file, reads (and displays) to the end, then monitoring for file size increases. When the file size increases, `tail` reads and displays from the former EOF position to the new end of file.

Comment: @waltinator I didn't really ask for myself. I asked him to add more details because his post was flagged low quality but I didn't want to vote to delete because he gave a correct answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I have used the `tail -50 {filename}` previously, but wasn't having success combining the two.

Comment: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=tail+-f+-n+%2B1

Comment: To save you a click: The `n` parameter that begins with the `+` sign refers to the position from the beginning of the file, while a number without any prefixes refers to the number of lines from the end of the file. So `-n +1` starts tailing from the beginning of the file and `-n 10` starts tailing from 10th line from the end of the file (where latter is the default behaviour if you omit the `-n` param).

Comment: @kraxor This shouldn't have been flagged as low quality in the first place, and the person who did flag it should be banned for abuse.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
watch tail {filename}
```

where `{filename}` is the file that you want to keep an eye on.  This will continuously monitor the command for changes and output the changes to stdout.  It's pretty handy.

Comment: This looks like a very nice tool. While it didn't quite give the results I was looking for, I will definitely keep it in mind. Combining it with the accepted answer is pretty nice: `watch tail -n +1 {filename}`

Comment: Yep, looks like you perfected it!

Comment: `watch` is really a useful tool but for watching of changing output of a command but to watch the end of a file being appended it is so much better to use `tail -f`. --- `watch tail {filename}` will reopen and reread the end of the file every two seconds. On the other hand `tail -f` watches for the file's growth and when detected it immediately reads just the appended part. `tailf -f` is much more efficient and the reaction is much faster. In addition it will continuously show the file content from the point where you begun. --- `watch` overwrites its output every two seconds.